# My “Alien Message” series

Tags: discussion, reference

This is an index of my posts related to my “Alien Message”.

## On Worldbuilding

- [Alien message: arrows and sequence order](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/71048/alien-message-arrows-and-sequence-order)
- [Recognizable natural numbers for alien message?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/70227/recognizable-natural-numbers-for-alien-message)
- [Alien message: “Invitation”](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/70640/alien-message-invitation)

## On other SE sites

- [Converting rational numbers to an “alien” data format](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/112370/converting-rational-numbers-to-an-alien-data-format)