# What reputation should you have to start a regular post?

Tags: discussion

I have seen some users on meta having a "regular post", series or feature that they do.

My question is: how much reputation should you have before starting one?

Comment: What do you mean with "regular post"? Do you mean something like a series, such as [Anatomcially Correct](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series)?

Comment: @Secespitus I first thought about it when i saw the "know your site monday" posts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The minimum required rep for creating a series of Meta posts such as "Know Your Site Monday" is the same as the required rep for creating an individual Meta post. In other words, **there's no specific rep requirement for it**. Nor is there a "soft limit" below which your series will simply be disregarded.

If you want to commit to something like that, though, you need to ensure you have:

1. A premise that's interesting enough to warrant such a series
2. Enough interesting material to warrant making it a **series**, and not a single post
3. The ability and motivation to stick to your chosen schedule

3 is the make-or-breaker. I don't know why kingledion stopped doing Know Your Site Monday but I'm willing to bet it was 3. I have two stories with a regular schedule (one weekly, one monthly) and I'm currently severely behind on both due to lack of motivation.

So to summarise: you can start a Meta series right this minute, but you have to be prepared to commit to it.

Answer (score 3):

#### You can start a series whenever you feel like it's a valuable addition to the site

You are asking about series of questions, the difference being series on Meta, such as [kingledion's *Know your site Monday* series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A23519+know+your+site+is%3Aq), and single posts on Meta with a list of questions on the Main Site like [TrEs-2b's *Anatomically Correct Series*](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series).

The latter is usually a collection of links about closely related topics, often framed in a similar way. Posting a Meta Post to collect them is a way to make the list easier for others to find. For example *Anatomically Correct* posts that want to be part of the series are encouraged to post a little link to the Meta Post in the question to give people interested in the topic a way to check out the whole series from different authors. See also [*Creating a realistic world* Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2594/creating-a-realistic-world-series) for another example.

There has been some discussion about this concept. Look for example at [Where can I post a Reference List?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5834/28789) where our mods James and MichaelKjörling explained that they do not think this is a good practice. Look through the discussions to get a better feeling, but the gist of it seems to be that the community is a bit split nowadays when it comes to these collections. If you have a lot of questions set in the same universe and you would like to do more than just link each one to the previous one you *could* think about creating a Meta Post to collect them. Whether or not that is a good idea is probably a case-by-case decision. Some work well (like *Anatomically Correct*, which has been around a while) and some do not, like JDługosz' [My “Alien Message” series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4639/my-alien-message-series) that also links to posts on other sites.

The second thing is the *Know your site Monday* series, which is (was?) a regular series of posts on Meta with (in my opinion) interesting information about the site. It's useful to have this information on Meta for those who are interested in getting information about the site and how to obtain such information through SEDE, while at the same time making it a little game of sorts.

Looking through the posts there was always a bit of downvoting involved. I assume that's because Meta is not supposed to be for *games*, but for *discussions* and the information should be given without waiting and be geared towards a specific goal. There was not a lot of discussion about the merit of the series as far as I am aware.

Personally I would say that you can think about creating a series of your own under the following conditions:

- you have something meaningful to say

  - either because you want to collect very similar posts from different sources and make them easily accessible
  - or you want to show data that could be useful for discussions in a format that is easy to understand
- you are reasonably sure that people would like to interact with your series

  - for example by posting questions in the same universe or with a similar style
  - or you want people to talk about the data you showed
- you have some other meaningful plan for the series, such as [regular topic challenges](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3483/should-we-end-the-topic-challenges) that were meant to increase the amount of questions in certain tags

You should not create a series when:

- you just want to promote your own questions
- you just want to talk about something only-slightly-related - the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor) might be a useful avenue for starting such discussions

Reputation should not play any role in all of this.